# Angle between North and East from magnetometer values

Tags: magnetometer

I have a magnetometer from where I get X, Y and Z which point to the direction of the detectable magnetic fields.

I'm using these values to get the angle between X and Y using atan2. I am a bit suprised of the result because North is not "aligned" with South. In fact there is not an angle of 90° between any "axes" (N, S, E or W).
I can reproduce it with my phone. Can someone explain me why ? Am I Wrong ? Am I missing something ?

In fact my real problem is that my angle is not "linear". For example, in the image below, between North and East, with atan2 I get 270° which is obviously wrong regarding to the direction.

Here below, what it looks like :

**magnetic cardinal points**

[image: 1]

**Edit :**

My magnetometer is a IIS2MDC mems from STMicroelectronic. I am getting values from registers with a nordic MCU (but it would be the same with a ST MCU)

Comment: I would love if someone helps you but I'm not sure you're on right forum and/or your question needs more specifics: what framework/language you use, what is the hardware/platform, i.e. how you got these values (API call? what API & what call/method?).

Comment: Hello, i edited my message with the type of sensor I am using. I don't know if I am on the right forum because I don't know if I am wrong using the hardware or wrong to understand the magnetic fields.

Comment: That's my concern: this forum is focused on programming, there are separate forums in stack exchange universe focused on hardware, IoT, Arduino... and Physics as well. Try (also) on Internet of Things.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I will try on electronics stack exchange. Should I keep this Question open ?

Comment: I would keep it open, why not.